# Extjs Validation Border not working

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Our validation border isn't working anymore in our application (It was working before). Unfortunately the bug is not reproducible in a fiddle, however I have tried to dig as deep as possible into the extJS code.

We have a method that shows the validation border on a component. The name and type are passed in and the GUI component is retrieved. This part always works

```
showValidationBorder: function (name, type) { //'myField' 'textfield'
    var _this = this;
    var cmp = this.queryGuiComponent(type, name); //got a cmp!!
    cmp.markInvalid('My Invalid Message!!!'); //:(
},
```

Now we call **markInvalid** on the component. markInvalid lives in **form.field.Base** class.

```
Ext.define('Ext.form.field.Base', {


    markInvalid : function(errors) {
        // Save the message and fire the 'invalid' event
        var me = this,
            oldMsg = me.getActiveError(),
            active;

        me.setActiveErrors(Ext.Array.from(errors)); //:(
        active = me.getActiveError();
        if (oldMsg !== active) {
            me.setError(active);
        }
    },
```

**setActiveErrors** is then called which lives in **Ext.form.Labelable**.

```
Ext.define("Ext.form.Labelable", {

    setActiveErrors: function(errors) {
        errors = Ext.Array.from(errors);
        this.activeError = errors[0];
        this.activeErrors = errors;
        this.activeError = this.getTpl('activeErrorsTpl').apply({ // :(
            errors: errors,
            listCls: Ext.plainListCls 
        });
        this.renderActiveError();
    },
```

**getTpl** is called which is in **Ext.AbstractComponent**. This method getTpl always returns null which is what is causing the 'undefined' error further in the chain.

```
Ext.define('Ext.AbstractComponent', {

    /**
     * @private
     */
    getTpl: function(name) {
        return Ext.XTemplate.getTpl(this, name); //:(
    },
```

This **getTpl** method is from **XTemplates** class.

```
Ext.define('Ext.XTemplate', {

        getTpl: function (instance, name) {
            var tpl = instance[name], // go for it! 99% of the time we will get it!
                owner;

            if (tpl && !tpl.isTemplate) { // tpl is just a configuration (not an instance)
                // create the template instance from the configuration:
                tpl = Ext.ClassManager.dynInstantiate('Ext.XTemplate', tpl);

                // and replace the reference with the new instance:
                if (instance.hasOwnProperty(name)) { // the tpl is on the instance
                    owner = instance;
                } else { // must be somewhere in the prototype chain
                    for (owner = instance.self.prototype; owner && !owner.hasOwnProperty(name); owner = owner.superclass) {
                    }
                }
                owner[name] = tpl;
                tpl.owner = owner;
            }
            // else !tpl (no such tpl) or the tpl is an instance already... either way, tpl
            // is ready to return

            return tpl || null;
        }
```

The getTpl function tries to get 'activeErrorTpl' from instance (which is the textfield). Because it can't the 'undefined' error is created. If we look at instance object it has similar object like 'acitveError', 'activeErrors', but no 'activeErrorTpl'.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what could be going wrong here? Do I need to set some kind of template for my validation error?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out what the problem is.

In out factory method for creating textfields we were setting the itemId inside the initComponent() method like this :

```
xtype: 'textfield',
cls: clazz,
name: config.name,
initComponent: function () {
    this.itemId = itemId;
},
```

If I just moved it to normal configuration then the problem dissapears :

```
xtype: 'textfield',
cls: clazz,
name: config.name,
itemId : itemId,
initComponent: function () {
    //this.itemId = itemId;
},
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this error originates from the fact that you implement the initComponent method and do not init the parent, e.g. you need to call "this.callParent()"